# ipython notebookで、削除したCellの復元方法を教えてください。

Tags: python

ipython notebookで、誤って「cut cell」で複数の削除してしまったCellを復元させる方法、もしくは開いた最初の状態に戻す方法でも構いません。

「Edit」→「Undo Delete Cell」ではひとつしか戻りません。

auto saveされてしまっているので、復元は無理なのでしょうか・・・？

コピーしていなかったので、悔やまれてなりません。
どうかお助けください。。。

※Windows使用です。

Answer (score 1):

復元したいcellが以前に評価したことがあるcellであれば

```
>>>> %history
```

で履歴を表示したり， リスト`In`に過去の入力の履歴が保持されているのでそれを確認してみます．

あと試したことはないですが， checkpointが作成されていればメニューの File->Revert to Checkpoint でcheckpointに戻せるようです．

Comment: ありがとうございます。
%history　で、実行した履歴を表示できるのですね。勉強不足でした。
ただ、保存てあったipynbファイルを開き、編集するために実行する前に削除をしてしまったので、戻したかったcellは表示されませんでした。。